# Creating time series DataFrame from event data

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataset of locations of stores with dates of events (the date all stock was sold from that store) and quantities of the sold items, such as the following:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

# Dates
start = pd.Timestamp("2014-02-26")
end = pd.Timestamp("2014-09-24")

# Generate some data
N = 1000
quantA = np.random.randint(10, 500, N)
quantB = np.random.randint(50, 250, N)
sell = np.random.randint(start.value, end.value, N)
sell = pd.to_datetime(np.array(sell, dtype="datetime64[ns]"))

df = pd.DataFrame({"sell_date": sell, "quantityA":quantA, "quantityB":quantB})
df.index = df.sell_date
```

I would like to create a new time series dataframe that has per-weekly summaries (or per daily; or per custom date_range object) from a range of these quantities A and B.

I can generate week number and aggregate sales based on those, like so...

```
df['week'] = df.sell_date.dt.week
df.pivot_table(values = ['quantityA', 'quantityB'], index = 'week', aggfunc = [np.sum, len])
```

But I don't see how to do the following:

1. expand this out to a full time series (based on a date_range object, such as `period_range = pd.date_range(start = start, end = end, freq='7D')`),
2. include the original date (as a 'week starting' variable), instead of integer week number, or
3. change the date variable to be the index of this new dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can try

```
df.set_index('sell_date', inplace=True) 
resampled = df.resample('7D', [sum, len])
```

The resulting index might not be exactly what you want as it starts with the earliest datetime correct to the nanosecond. You could replace with datetimes which have 00:00:00 in the time by doing

```
resampled.index = pd.to_datetime(resampled.index.date)
```

EDIT:

You can actually just do

```
    resampled = df.resample('W', [sum, len])
```

And the resulting index is exactly what you want. Interestingly, passing `'D'` also gives the index you would expect but passing a multiple like `'2D'` results in the 'ugly' index, that is, starting at the earliest correct to the nanosecond and increasing in multiples of exactly 2 days. I guess the lesson is stick to singles like 'D', 'W', 'M' where possible.

EDIT:
The API for resampling changed at some point such that the above no longer works. Instead one can do:

```
resampled = df.resample('W').agg([sum, len])
```

`.resample` now returns a `Resampler` object which exposes methods, much like the `groupby`API.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Just to be complete, I've added `df.index = df.sell_date` to my answer and then your answer works completely.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this with a custom date_range?  For instance if I wanted weekly summaries for the whole of the year 2014?

Comment: Well you can set the period by replacing 'W' with whatever you want. To limit the range you can do various things but I think `df.loc['20140101': '20141231'].resample...` would be the cleanest in this case. When you say the whole of 2014, do you mean as a subset of same larger data set? In your example the data is limited to 2014.

Comment: Think I found what I wanted, I meant this... `period_range = pd.date_range(start = '2014-01-01', end = '2014-12-13', freq='7D');`

`resampled = df.resample('D', [sum, len]);`
`resampled.reindex(period_range)`

Thanks for the help!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? This would give the daily sum of dates which are one week from '2014-01-01', i.e. all the Wednesdays in the year. It doesn't give weekly sums.

Comment: I just want it for custom date ranges.  I see what you mean, I might not want from this specific date I've used as an example, but I can use the same method to get sums on each week starting from the first Sunday of 2014 onwards.  For instance,
`period_range = pd.date_range(start = '2014-01-05', end = '2014-12-31', freq='7D'); resampled = df.resample('D', [sum, len]); resampled.reindex(period_range)`

Comment: This will not return weekly sums! `df.resample('D', [sum, len])` gives daily sums. Reindexing with `period_range` will simply return a view of of the sum on each Sunday of the year, not the weekly sum to each Sunday. If you want weekly sums to Sunday you have to resample with weekly frequency.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  So `resampled = df.resample('W', [sum, len]); resampled.reindex(period_range)` seems to work, right?

Comment: @JoeCondron That's threw out `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. maybe this answer needs to be updated due to recent update of numpy & pandas packages when I tried in [google colab medium](https://colab.research.google.com/)