# How can build a dataframe for time-series data with clear time-stamps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, time-series

For my experiment, I have a formatted [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YgbhwIgnW42bwOnaxM2e_JHwsf3Q9O2_/view?usp=sharing) file which looks like a matrix[NxM] where N = 40 total number of cycles(time-stamps) and M = 1440 pixels. For every cycle, I have 1440 pixel values corresponding to 1440 pixels. like following:

```
timestamps[row_index] | feature1  | feature2 | ... | feature1439 | feature1440 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
       1              |  1.00     |   0.32   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   | 
       2              |  0.35     |   0.33   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   | 
       3              |  1.00     |   0.33   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   | 
      ...             |   ....    |   ....   |   ....   |   ....  |   ....   | 
                      | -1.00     |   0.26   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   | 
                      |   0.67    |   0.03   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   | 
       30             |   0.75    |   0.42   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   |
________________________________________________________________________________ 
      31              |  -0.36    |   0.42   |   0.30   |   0.30  |   0.30   | 
      ...             |   ....    |   ....   |   ....   |   ....  |   ....   | 
      40              |   1.00    |   0.34   |   0.30   |   0.30  |  -1.00   |
```

[image: img]

I would like to slice data-set into train-set and test-set such a way that:

Train-set contains [1-30]   time-stamps info

Test-set contains [31-40]   time-stamps info

The problem is I couldn't achieve proper continuous plot after training NN most probably due to bad data split technique I've used via `train_test_split` but never tried by `TimeSeriesSplit` as following :

```
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX,trainY, test_size=0.2 , shuffle=False)
```

considering I've used `shuffle=False` and expect that 0.2 of from **end of** data will be considered as test data and I can get plot them correctly but still can't access the number of cycles which are considered as test data , therefore when I plot it starts from 0 ! instead of continue of the last cycle of train data!

I was wondering if it is better to pass the data to `pd.DataFrame` and try slicing data by `pd.Timestamp` based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32074664/10452700)! Is it helpful or is it unnecessary?

**Update- full code:** 
my columns labeling follows below pattern by just predict that 960 out of 1440 columns :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.layers import Dense , Activation , BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM,SimpleRNN
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

data_train = pd.read_csv("D:\train.csv", header=None)
#select interested columns to predict 980 out of 1440
j=0
index=[]
for i in range(1439):
    if j==2:
        j=0
        continue
    else:
        index.append(i)
        j+=1

Y_train= data_train[index]
data_train = data_train.values
print("data_train size: {}".format(Y_train.shape))
```

**Making History**

```py
def create_dataset(dataset,data_train,look_back=1):
    dataX,dataY = [],[]
    print("Len:",len(dataset)-look_back-1)

    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(data_train[i + look_back,  :])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 10
trainX,trainY = create_dataset(data_train,Y_train, look_back=look_back)
#testX,testY = create_dataset(data_test,Y_test, look_back=look_back)
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX,trainY, test_size=0.2)
print("train size: {}".format(trainX.shape))
print("train Label size: {}".format(trainY.shape))
print("test size: {}".format(testX.shape))
print("test Label size: {}".format(testY.shape))
```

```py
Len: 29
train size: (23, 10, 1440)
train Label size: (23, 960)
test size: (6, 10, 1440)
test Label size: (6, 960)
```

**RNN, LSTM, GRU implementation similarly**

```py
# create and fit the SimpleRNN model
model_RNN = Sequential()
model_RNN.add(SimpleRNN(units=1440, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model_RNN.add(Dense(960))
model_RNN.add(BatchNormalization())
model_RNN.add(Activation('tanh'))
model_RNN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.1, patience=3, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=1)]
hist_RNN=model_RNN.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs =50, batch_size =20,validation_data=(testX,testY),verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)
```

in the end I would expected following output plot:

```py
Y_RNN_Test_pred=model_RNN.predict(testX)
test_RNN= pd.DataFrame.from_records(Y_RNN_Test_pred)
test_RNN.to_csv('New/ttest_RNN_history.csv', sep=',', header=None, index=None)
test_MSE=mean_squared_error(testY, Y_RNN_Test_pred)

plt.plot(trainY[:,0],'b-',label='Train data')
plt.plot(testY[:,0],'c-',label='Test data')
plt.plot(Y_RNN_Test_pred[:,0],'r-',label='prediction')
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a small problem with the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('Train.csv', header=None)

# I'm not sure what the label-column is, so i use df[0]
# and exclude this colums in the data via df.loc[:,df.columns!=0]
trainX,testX,trainY,testY = train_test_split(df.loc[:,df.columns!=0],df[0], test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

plt.plot(trainY)
plt.plot(testY)
```

[image]

seems fine. :-)

so now we want to predict:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
reg = SVR(C=1, gamma='auto')
reg.fit(trainX, trainY) 
predY = reg.predict(testX)

plt.plot(trainY)
plt.plot(testY)
plt.plot(predY)
```

[image]

The index is wrong :-(
Let's fix this, e.g. use the index of `testY`:

```
plt.plot(trainY)
plt.plot(testY)
plt.plot(testY.index,predY)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

A more generic solution is to take the range of the length of your train dataset and set it as index, same with `testY` and `predY`, just with a different start value (length of `trainY`)

```
trainY.index = range(len(trainY))
testY.index = range(len(trainY), len(trainY)+len(testY))
#Maybe convert to DataFrame first
predY = pd.DataFrame(predY)
predY.index = range(len(trainY), len(trainY)+len(predY))

plt.plot(trainY)
plt.plot(testY)
plt.plot(predY)
```

**Edit based on your new code**

```
trainY.index = range(len(trainY))
testY.index = range(len(trainY), len(trainY)+len(testY))
test_RNN.index = range(len(trainY), len(trainY)+len(test_RNN))

plt.plot(trainY,'b-',label='Train data')
plt.plot(testY,'c-',label='Test data')
plt.plot(test_RNN,'r-',label='prediction')
```

**Edit 2**

Ok, lets go through your code step by step:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Dense , Activation , BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM,SimpleRNN
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

data_train = pd.read_csv("Train.csv", header=None)
#select interested columns to predict 980 out of 1440
```

Actually your select only 960 columns to predict, see below.

```
#j=0
#index=[]
#for i in range(1439):
#    if j==2:
#        j=0
#        continue
#    else:
#        index.append(i)
#        j+=1

idx2 = [i for i in list(range(1440)) if i%3!=2]
```

If I understood your loop right, you just want take every three of two values. So list comprehension is a bit more faster `idx2 = [i for i in list(range(1440)) if i%3!=2]`. You probably also want to have all columns included? So use `1440` instead of `1439`.

```
Y_train= data_train[index]
data_train = data_train.values
print("data_train size: {}".format(Y_train.shape))
```

In your code the shape of `Y_train` is `(40,960)`. So, you want to predict 690 variables, right? If so, the "clean" way would be to remove those columns from `data_train` (and make a `X_train`):

```
index2 = [i for i in list(range(1440)) if i%3==2]
X_train = data_train[index2]
```

Now lets check the shapes:

```
print("X_train size: {}".format(X_train.shape))
print("Y_train size: {}".format(Y_train.shape))

>X_train size: (40, 480)
>Y_train size: (40, 960)
```

Seems right... ;-)

I made some modifications on the next part:
- You do not need to subtract `1` inside the range (`for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):`. Unlike some other programming languages, Python does not include the last value, so e.g. if you do `list(range(0,3))`, the list would be `[0,1,2]`. **Probably these are your missing 10 values (the last ones)...**
- I took also the `values` from `Y_train`

```
def create_dataset(dataset,data_train,look_back=1):
    dataX,dataY = [],[]

    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(data_train[i+look_back, :])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 10
trainX,trainY = create_dataset(X_train.values, Y_train.values, look_back=look_back)
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX,trainY, test_size=0.2)
```

```
print("train size: {}".format(trainX.shape))
print("train Label size: {}".format(trainY.shape))
print("test size: {}".format(testX.shape))
print("test Label size: {}".format(testY.shape))

>train size: (24, 10, 480)
>train Label size: (24, 960)
>test size: (6, 10, 480)
>test Label size: (6, 960)
```

I had to add two imports to the training `from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau`, so:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
# create and fit the SimpleRNN model
model_RNN = Sequential()
model_RNN.add(SimpleRNN(units=1440, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model_RNN.add(Dense(960))
model_RNN.add(BatchNormalization())
model_RNN.add(Activation('tanh'))
model_RNN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.1, patience=3, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=1)]
hist_RNN=model_RNN.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs =50, batch_size =20,validation_data=(testX,testY),verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Make the predictions (unmodified):

```
Y_RNN_Test_pred=model_RNN.predict(testX)
test_RNN= pd.DataFrame.from_records(Y_RNN_Test_pred)
#test_RNN.to_csv('New/ttest_RNN_history.csv', sep=',', header=None, index=None)
test_MSE=mean_squared_error(testY, Y_RNN_Test_pred)
```

and plot the data with the modifications in the x-axis as explained above:

```
x_start =  range(look_back, look_back+len(trainY))
x_train_start = range(look_back + len(trainY), look_back + len(trainY)+len(testY))
x_pred_start = range(look_back + len(trainY), look_back +len(trainY)+len(Y_RNN_Test_pred))
plt.plot(x_start, trainY[:,0],'b-',label='Train data')
plt.plot(x_train_start, testY[:,0],'c-',label='Test data')
plt.plot(x_pred_start, Y_RNN_Test_pred[:,0],'r-',label='prediction')
```

[image]

Comment: oh, looks good but what about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277603/how-can-slice-the-time-series-data-with-multi-features-to-get-continuous-plot-co) when I use same scenario with **history-based** approach, unfortunately I miss 10 cycles because of history function def create_dataset() which check the the past 10 cycles to forecast the future one. would you for your answer for this approach as well?

Comment: @Mario, It depends on your data ( the post is missing the types / indexes e.g.), but I updated my post, maybe that helps. :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually data was the same dataset but I update my question with full-code so that you might understand columns labeling which is done by selecting interested columns indexes and replace right part instead of `df[0]` so that NN can predict 960 out of 1440 columns, another issue is I'm unsure that **history-based** approach which is prediction based on the last 10 cycles implemented right or not?! I tried as it can be seen in **Making History**  by `def create_dataset()` but it affects on results of splitting !! I miss 10 cycle due to I set `lookback=10`.Any ideas to fix?

Comment: Do you have any ideas to fix it? it's highly important for me

Comment: @Mario, no sorry, I thought is was "only an index"-Error, but I dont know if your history-based approach is the right one. :-(

Comment: ok then let's igonre **history-based** scenario , at least plz help me to find elegant code to put right labeling instead of `df[0]` based on : `j=0
index=[]
for i in range(1439):
    if j==2:
        j=0
        continue
    else:
        index.append(i)
        j+=1` it's mentioned in my full-code in end of the post. please have a look.

Comment: I will try, but I am not sure, if I understood you right. Could you try the code in my new edit? Insert the reindexing and the new plt fuctions.

Comment: Based on last example of this [article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/predicting-stock-price-machine-learningnd-deep-learning-techniques-python/) for LSTM I would like to the apply the similar approach on my data which I explained in this [picture](https://i.imgur.com/D6T04xr.jpg) how I label interested columns by indexing and how I would like to access the slice point and get plot final plot by clear and continuous cycle number.

Comment: @Mario, took a while... but I went over your whole code, see my edit ;-)

Comment: Man it's very nice of you to take a time for that. I was waiting for your feedback. I would like to point out that Yes I suppose to predict 960 out of 1440 but why i didn't clean it is due to these 1440 values for each cycle are actually belong to pixel of three 24*20 matrices. The real idea behind was that there is a **correlation** between all pixels and we would like NN learn this correlation and predict base on that if it can see it. That's why by arranging all pixels of 3 matrices in each row which is one cycle try t participate all in learning process & just predict 960 of'em in output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194015/discussion-between-ilja-and-mario).